# Using the request module

Tags: node.js

How can I call the request function more than once if I want to scrape a website let says every one to five minutes autonomously? I was using a do-while loop but it does not wait for the code to be completed before running again, it just a skips everything.

```
do{
request('http://www.google.com', function(err, resp, html){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        url = $('b')[0].children[0].data
        urls.push(url)
        console.log(url);

        fs.writeFile("test.txt",urls,function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        })       
    }
});
}while (counter == 0)
```

Comment: A code snippit would be very helpful.  From your description, my first guess is that it's calling a callback, but the loop will still end.

Comment: Sorry, I was just adding it I was on mobile.

Comment: And you're not seeing any output?  Would you try logging if there is an error from `request`?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything I added a incrementing variable and console.log it and it shows. It looks like it's skipping everything within the request function.

Comment: What is mean is `if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){ ... } else {console.log("error")}`.  I have a feeling it's not getting into the if statement.

Comment: I think that just a condition to see if the page can open. I'm able to run the code without the do-while loop so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding a timer so it runs every few seconds instead of as fast as your compute can count.

Comment: How would I do that? setInterval?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80709/discussion-between-brennan-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply solve the problem you are having, you should look into [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) instead of trying to use a modulus on the `minutes` of a `Date` object.

Something like:

```
setInterval(scrape, 1000 * 60); //1000ms = 1 second.  1 second * 60 = 1 minute
```

will work if you have your request logic inside of a function called `scrape`.

If you want to build a more sophisticated tool you can check out the link in the other answer, otherwise this should get you unblocked.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Node is asynchronous. and that is why you see it skipping everything inside your loop, instead of putting your implementation inside a loop i would advice you to check some very well known node modules which are designed to step over those implemenations and makes it easy on you to design your code in a very nice "async" fashion, like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) if you are a fan of Javascript promises instead of callbacks.

Further more, if you wish to scrap the web, there are a plenty of [scraping modules](https://www.google.jo/search?q=npm%20web%20scraper&oq=npm%20web%20scraper) which might be useful for your situation.